# Highcharts stacked column don't show the stacked with min value

Tags: highcharts

Can anyone help me with highcharts stacked column my problem is that i have big difference with data and the graph show me only the big data.
i try minPointLength but don't help in my case. please check here the example: http://jsfiddle.net/17jd6frn/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {

            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [2000, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [7000, 2, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a logarithmic scale (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.type).  It will show your small numbers and your large numbers.  Note, that you can't show 0 or negative numbers on a log scale.

```
yAxis: [{
  type: "logarithmic",
  min: 1,
  title: {
    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
  },
  stackLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
    }
  }
}],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17jd6frn/1/

Comment: Thank you so much is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with you. 
1.) Either use "minPointLength". This is the minimum value for for the y-axis plotting.You can use this setting and set this to a value which will always be shown in case the value gets too small for plotting. You can use this setting like

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked column chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {

        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        },
        stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            },
    minPointLength: 5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [7000, 5, 1, 1, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2000, 10, 1, 1, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [5, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    }]
});
});
```

2.) You can change the "stacking" option to 'percent' and remove the 'minPointLength' . This will cause the stacked columns to appear w.r.t to their value percentages.

Please play with the above two options and see if it works for you !!!